# Returning the address of a vlookup function in vba

Tags: vba, excel

I've looked through all guides I can find on this subject but not a single one solves my problem.
I want to find the cell address of this vlookup function:

```
vlookadd = Application.Lookup(partno, Sheet3.Range("A5:B46"), 2, False)
```

(Currently dimmed as variant incase that needs to be changed)
I want to find the address of the value found and make it equal a variable so something like this:

```
batch1add = vlookadd.Address
```

The value found by the lookup function works fine but the address always comes up empty after trying lots of different possible solutions

Comment: Would be worth looking at [FIND](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find) to find the `partno` and then offset from the returned range reference.

Comment: [Lookup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.lookup) will return the value of the cell, not the cell itself.

Comment: Also your `Lookup` syntax looks wrong, did you mean to use `vlookup` instead? Because `Lookup` only has 3 parameters but you used 4.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ yeah that was just a typo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as well as using `find`

`cells(worksheetfunction.match(partno,range("a5:a46"),0)+4,2).address`

The plus 4 is due to the start row of the range being 5, for example a match in row 5 will return 1.

Comment: I think you must match column A not B: `Range("A5:A46")`. Also it would throw an error if there is no match, so some error handling would be a good idea.

Comment: was just about to say it didnt work then you editted B to A and now it works exactly as intended, thanks

Comment: If you use `With Range("A5:A46"): Debug.Print .Cells(WorksheetFunction.Match(partno, .Cells, 0), 2).Address : End With` you don't have to care about the beginning row and don't have to think about the  `+4` at all (because all row counting is relative to the range, but `.Address` still returns the absolute address).

Answer (score 0):

Per the comments, using Find and an offset should be just fine.

```
Function getAddress(itemToFind As Variant, lookupRange As Range, columnOffset As Integer)

    getAddress = lookupRange.Find(What:=itemToFind).Offset(0, columnOffset).address

End Function
```

---

```
Sub Example()

    Dim batch1add As String

    Set batch1add = getAddress(partno, Sheet3.Range("A5:B46"), 2)

End Sub
```

As PEH advised in the prior answer's comments: Incorporating some error handling would be wise, as both implementations assume the value exists whenever they're called.